# Is it possible to separate SSDs from HDDs in a RAID array?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid

Is it possible to make 2 SSDs work together separately from 2 HDDs in a RAID array?

I have motherboard ([ASUS Z170-A](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z170-A/)) that supports RAID and would like to have a configuration like this:

```
     RAID 0                         RAID 0
      /\                              /\
  ____||____                      ____||____    
 |          |                    |          |
 |          |                    |          |
SSD1       SSD2                 HDD1       HDD2
```

You see that—in my idea for a setup—SSDs and HDDs would not interfere each other.

Is this possible to do with one RAID controller?

Comment: Yes i want ssd work only with ssds and hdds with hdds... this will make two separate arrays i guess. Data does not go from hdd to sdd with raid

Comment: Its ASUS Z170-A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is most certannly possible to do, and on that board also.
You have 6 SATA ports, plus the express ports (shared with M2).

It is also common—and somewhat smart to form—2 seperate arrays when doing (for example) 4 hard disks, because copying from/to utilizes 2 seperate sets of hardware storage, instead of doing “I-While-O” doing input and output from the same set of 4 disk items.

It is therfore usually preferable to do 2x2 arrays, then to bundle all 4 disks up (in the case of 4 similar hard drives) because you can copy from one array to the other in very high speeds.

Something to also consider—for reasons to keep the hard drives separated—depending on usage patterns it might be better to have them as completely seperated hardware.

While one would show really good benchmarks of speed, whenever you are writing back to that single team, from that single team, it is slow.  With 2 teams one reading one writing, it is much better.

When teaming up 2 fast disks (SSD) in RAID instead of from the M2 with one, also consider that there could be times where the rate of data moving, and software combining on the communications bus, could cause a balking of other processes. People reported that back in the early days of SSD—and still sometimes report—some odd balking with 2X SSD in RAID.  Good to test your SSD raiding setup early with a high level task that includes data transfers and cpu use at the same time.

Conclusion: Sure that is possible, done quite often, usually would not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, one would never mix the SSDs and the HDDs on the same raid 0 "array" , it would work but be very unbalanced. Going off the picture in the Question, it is the same controller, but a seperate SSD array and a seperate Hard drive array.  Which brings up also having 2 raid controllers :-) as more seperated hardware , which I do here, so I get full speed from/to copying between 2x quad teams of disks. Way overboard, but it works "faster".